# How to compare DataTable row with listbox items

Tags: c#, mysql, foreach, datatable, listbox

I wanna compare list items in a listbox with with a DataTable column rows named "time" when I select a date in the monthcalendar, Im trying to remove the items in the listbox if they are equal to the values in the column, if not then use the default items I have in the begining. But Iam getting the message: item colection cannot be modified when Datasource property is set. Please help me correct the code:

```
   private void monthCAL_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        string date = monthCAL.SelectionStart.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        string connetionString = null;
        MySqlConnection connection;
        MySqlCommand command;
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string sql = null;
        connetionString = "datasource=localhost; database=bokning;port=3306;username=root;password=666666";
        sql = "select day, time from system where day='" + date + "'";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            adapter.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
            connection.Close();

            MyDateT = ds.Tables[0];

            if (MyDateT.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in MyDateT.Rows) { 
                    for (int i = 0; i < MydefaultList.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (MydefaultList[i].ToString().Equals(dr["time"].ToString())) {
                            listB1.Items.Remove(MydefaultList[i]);
                            //listB1.DataSource = MydefaultList;
                        }
                    }
            }                  
            }
            else
            {
                listB1.DataSource = MydefaultList;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you are not able to remove items from a `Listbox` that have a `DataSource` property.

This link can describe more in depth:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/758161/Items-collection-cannot-be-modified-when-the-DataS

You will need to set the `DataSource` to null, make the changes you want to make and then re-add the `DataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new list to store the limited options. Please see the edited code below.

```
      private void monthCAL_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    string date = monthCAL.SelectionStart.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    string connetionString = null;
    MySqlConnection connection;
    MySqlCommand command;
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string sql = null;
    connetionString = "datasource=localhost; database=bokning;port=3306;username=root;password=666666";
    sql = "select day, time from system where day='" + date + "'";
    connection = new MySqlConnection(connetionString);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        adapter.Dispose();
        command.Dispose();
        connection.Close();

        MyDateT = ds.Tables[0];
        List<string> limitedList = MyDefaultList; //added line

        if (MyDateT.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in MyDateT.Rows) { 
                for (int i = 0; i < MydefaultList.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (MydefaultList[i].ToString().Equals(dr["time"].ToString())) {
                        limitList.Remove(MyDefaultList[i]);
                        listB1.DataSource = limitedList;
                        //listB1.Items.Remove(MydefaultList[i]); offending line
                        //listB1.DataSource = MydefaultList; offending line
                    }
                }
        }                  
        }
        else
        {
            listB1.DataSource = MydefaultList;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: It just removing the the first compared selected date in the database from the list, after that nothing more happens when trying compare other dates, my MyDefaultList is: List<string> MydefaultList = new List<string>(); MydefaultList.Add("08:00-12:00");
            MydefaultList.Add("12:00-16:00");
            MydefaultList.Add("16:00-20:00");
            for (int i = 0; i < MydefaultList.Count; i++)
            {
                listB1.Items.Add(MydefaultList[i]);
                
            }